# DAX prevent date filter from influencing calculation REMOVEFILTERS and ALL did not work

Tags: powerbi, dax

this is my second post and I hope I am coming to grips with the formatting. Please let me know if I am providing too little or too much information.

As a stepping stone for solving a more complex problem, I need to calculate  First Order Date from a table that will not be influenced by the quarter date selected in the report slicer.

This is my calendar DAX:

```
DateTable = ADDCOLUMNS(CALENDARAUTO(),
"MonthNo", MONTH([Date]),
"MonthName", FORMAT([Date],"MMMM"),
"Quarter", QUARTER([Date]),
"Year", YEAR([Date]),
"Day", DAY([Date]),
"WeekdayNum", WEEKDAY([Date]),
"WeekdayName",FORMAT([Date],"DDDD"),
"YearMonth", FORMAT([Date], "YYYY-MM"),
"YearQuarter", FORMAT([Date], "YYYY-Q"))
```

[Screenshot of the data model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ccXWI.png)

So far, I have tried a few variations. At the moment, I have tried this code:

```
FirstOrderDate = CALCULATE(MIN('invoices_2019-2022'[Date Initiated]), 
ALL(DateTable[Date]))
```

That works fine as long as I have not selected any quarter in the slicer.

[Screenshot of result WITHOUT selected YearQuarter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vK9Yu.png)

However, as soon as I select a YearQuarter in the slicer, the results change:

[Screenshot of result with selected YearQuarter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cBot8.png)

So, the code no longer returns the actual first order date, only the first order date in the context of the slicer. despite the ALL function.

Next, I tried this:

```
FirstOrderDate = CALCULATE(MIN('invoices_2019-2022'[Date Initiated]), 
REMOVEFILTERS(DateTable[Date]))
```

Same result.

I have googled this thing to death and also tried variations of MINX, and a few other things.

I really have NO idea why this is and how I can make it work.

Please help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do `ALL` or `REMOVEFILTERS` on the whole table or the relevant column.

So try:

```
ALL(DateTable)
// or
REMOVEFITLERS(DateTable)
```

Comment: That does it. Thanks a lot.